# Destroy a GameObject in Hierachy that has no Children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I would like to make it so that in a script I can find out if an object in my hierarchy has a child and if it doesn't, destroy it. I would also like to know how in a script, create the same gameobject as one in my hierarchy, i.e. duplicate an object in my hierarchy.

I couldn't find anything on the sites.

Comment: What have you done to research this? Unity documentation is pretty comprehensive in this sort of thing

Comment: You might be searching for the wrong keywords. For example, your post title has almost no relevance to the question you’re asking. What is the “variable” you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deleting objects that do not have a child**

You can create a script like this:

```
public GameObject gm;

if (gm.transform.childCount != 0)
{
     // The object has a child.
     // Do whatever you want here.
}
else
{
     // The object do not have a child.
     // Destroy the object.
     Destroy(gm);
}
```

If you want, you can even create a method that does that!

```
public void DeleteObject(GameObject gm)
{
    if (gm.transform.childCount == 0)
    {
        // The object do not have a child.
        // Destroy the object.
        Destroy(gm);
    }
}
```

**Duplicating Objects**

About the "Duplicate Object", you can use this method:

```
 // You can call this method whenever you like and pass in the object that you want to duplicate.
 public void DuplicateObject(GameObject obj)
 {
      Instantiate(obj);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is totally what I was looking for, and it is very well explained.

Comment: @Gryffox Nice! I'm glad I could help you!
Consider accepting the answer, this way other people with the same problem can see that it fixed the problem.